# Cant assign a string to a list to manipulate a value

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

```py
current_game = [
    ['y', 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 1]
]
current_game[0][0][0] = "X"
print(current_game)
```

This gives me an error when I run the code. "TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: `current_game` is a 2D list. You can do `current_game[0][0] = "X"`

Answer (score 1):

Look at what you've written and break it down:

`current_game[0]` refers to

```
['y', 1, 1]
```

And `current_game[0][0]` refers to

```
'y'
```

So `current_game[0][0][0]` is referring to the *first letter of* your string (of length one).

You're trying to change the first letter of that string, but strings are immutable in Python.

I think you might intend to replace the string in the list, not modify it. In that case, remove one level of array access:

```
current_game[0][0] = "X"
```

Comment: I thought it was a 3 dimensional array as my IDE filled in the outer squared brackets, to differentiate it from  a tuple. Upon reading the comments, i'v realised it's a 2D array! Thanks